# For which $u\in\mathbb{C}$ is $0^{u}$ defined?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

It is obvious that $\left|e^{v}\right|=e^{\text{Re }v}>0$ showing
that $\ln z$ is not defined for $z=0$ .

So the expression $z^{u}=e^{u\ln z}$ cannot be used here.

Nevertheless we don't hesitate to say things like: $0^{3}=0\times0\times0=0$.

Are there some conventions here?

Comment: For integer exponents, when considering fixed exponents, we have unambiguously $0^n = 0$ for $n > 0$, $0^n = \infty$ for $n < 0$, and $0^0 = 1$ by considering the type of the isolated singularity in $0$. For non-integer exponents, one sometimes posits $0^u = 0$ if $\operatorname{Re} u > 0$ and $0^u = \infty$ if $\operatorname{Re} u < 0$.

Comment: I like this convention.  $0^b$, for $b$ a positive integer, is $0$.  $0^b$, where $b$ is the integer $0$, is $1$.  $0^b$ for other $b$ is undefined.  And (of course) $a^b$ for nonzero complex $a$ is defined by $\exp(b\log a)$, which may be multi-valued.  NOTE: Even if $b$ is the complex number $0$, or the real number $0$, I still want $0^b$ undefined.

Comment: I think it would be absurd not to let $0^3$ equal $0$. Daniel's idea allows this because $\operatorname{Re}(3)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is *not* obvious that $|e^v|=e^{\operatorname{Re}v}$. It is true nonetheless. And the fact that $\ln z$ is not defined when $z=0$ is more basic than that. In fact $\ln z$ is a number such that $e^{\ln z}=z$. But we never have $e^v=0$, since $e^v.e^{-v}=1$.

The concept of $a^n$, when $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is more elementary than the concept of exponential function. It just means$$\overbrace{a\times a\times\cdots\times a}^{n\text{ times}}.$$It turns out that, when $a\neq0$, this is equal to $e^{n\log a}$, where $\log a$ is *any* logarithm of $a$. But we don't need this to *define* $a^n$. And, by the definition that I mentioned, it is clear that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):0^n=0.$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you also have an answer to the question in the title?

Comment: @drhab I think that the only complex numbers $u$ such that $0^u$ is defined are those $u$'s which are real numbers greater than $0$ and that, in that case, $0^u=0$. Thet's because if $u$ is rational and greater than $0$, then you can write $u=\frac pq$, with $p$ and $q$ relatively prime natural numbers, and define, when $x\geqslant 0$, $x^u$ as $\sqrt[q]{x^p}$. With this definition, $0^u=0$ and you can extend the definition to real exponents greater than or equal to $0$ using limits.

Comment: Thank you again. It strikes me that in the comments concerning this question - yours also - I meet the words "I think" or "I like" quite often. Apparantly there is not a great need for conventions on this topic.