# Is it true that $0^r =0$ for all $r > 0$?

Tags: exponentiation

Is it true that $0^r =0$ For all $r > 0$?

It comes in the context of real exponentiation as most of the text (e.g. Tao Analysis 1) defines $x^y$ for $x>0$ and not for $x=0$ when y is arbitrary real number

Comment: Yes, this is the usual way to define $0^r,r>0$.

Comment: This is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550560/75923). It might be useful to take a look.

Comment: It is easy to show from the very definition of exponentiation that $0^q=0$ holds for all rationals.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Even negative rationals?

Comment: @FrankVel: you are right to correct me. All positive rationals. (That was too implicit in my mind.)

Comment: Is it possible to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}0^{a_n}=0^r$ where $a_n$ are rationals such that $a_n\to0$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2499331/306553 didn't you just askthe question here?